# How to stop the vibrations/sound produced by glass inside a room while playing a speaker system?

Tags: sound-proofing, glass, home-theater, speakers, vibration

My room has a sealed glass (like window glass but we can can't open and close; its fixed to the frame). Whenever I play music in my 5.1 speakers, the glass starts vibrating making a "errrrrr/grrrrr" sound. It stops when I put my hand on the glass.

Any ideas to prevent the vibration sound, so that I could take my hands off the glass and enjoy the music?

[image: Irritating Glass]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your subwoofer settings to determine at what level the vibration starts or stops? Is the grid work that we see in the window sandwiched in between two panes of glass where is it touching the glass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes rope caulk

[image: Rope Caulk]

applied along the edges of the glass will keep it from vibrating.  You might have to apply it on both sides to get it to work.  This might not do the trick, but it's cheap easy and easily undoable if it doesn't work.  Hopefully you can go back to dancing around with both hands.

Comment: I never heard of the rope caulk. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the putty holding the glass in place.
Check for looseness in the glass - it should be held in place with thin nails running parallel with the glass and into the frame. If it's loose, carefully tap in a few extra nails before reapplying the putty around the edges of the glass.

Another option would be to throw a large brick at the window. It's unlikely to vibrate with a large hole in it!